# Symfony: implementing authentication from and external project

Tags: symfony

I have 3 symfony projects each one has it's own login page.
I want to make another symofony project that will work as the authentication gate, where a user can login to the other projects from it.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install a SSO (like CAS for example) on a server.
And then use this SSO on your project : https://github.com/PRayno/CasAuthBundle (if you use CAS)

Comment: what SSO is ? first time I hear of it.

Comment: Single Sign On. It is a login process like Facebook connect. https://auth0.com/blog/what-is-and-how-does-single-sign-on-work/